# Python string to html javascript block with jinja2

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a problem for passing a string to html page. Specifically in "< script>" block. I using Python, Flask, Jinja2 ...

**In python I have something like this:**

```
def foo():
  return myString #"[{title: 'Treino 7-Corrida',start: '2015-12-08',color: '#d00000',textColor: '#00c028'}]"
```

**In html I have something like this:**

```
<html>
...
{{myString}} <!-- jinja2 -->
...
<script>
...
{{myString}}  <!-- jinja2 -->
...
</script>
</html>
```

**Viewing source code I have this:**

```
<html>
...
[{title: 'Treino 7-Corrida',start: '2015-12-08',color: '#d00000',textColor: '#00c028'}]
...
<script>
...
[{title: &#39;Treino 7-Corrida&#39;,start: &#39;2015-12-08&#39;,color: &#39;#d00000&#39;,textColor: &#39;#00c028&#39;}]
...
</script>
</html>
```

The question is:

What I do that script don't replace ' for code &#39 ;?

Comment: Try `{{ myString | safe }}` ?

Comment: Tks  lord63 this fix the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Because the variables are escaped, jinja2 autoescape is enabled for html.

You should try the [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#safe) filter:

> Mark the value as safe which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped.

so edit the html to this one:

```
{{ myString | safe }}
```